# get notification while app in background after capture image from camera

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

My app is running background and now i capture image from camera , is it possible to get image or any notification in my app after capture image?

Comment: You cannot manipulate camera app of iOS, and therefore you will never get a notification when the image is captured from the camera.

Answer (score 1):

Your application can notify the user \ you only about what's going on inside the eco system of  **your** application. There's no way to handle other processes that are running on iOS such as the camera unless it was called from inside your app.

Comment: Dropbox asks for permission accessing your photos album and then uploads it. It will keep doing so when the app is open and compare between the photos on your dropbox account vs the one in your photo album. Nothing magical about it.

Comment: Thanks for help.Have you idea For comparison they use Timestamp or image data?

Comment: Probably image size + name + meta data \ date taken etc'.. Please accept the answer if it helped you.